# Does ServiceStack support any kind of persistent connections?

Tags: servicestack

I am working on a project where I need clients to be able to open a persistent connection to the server over which the server can send periodic updates back to the client.  Does ServiceStack provide any tools to help in this scenario?

Comment: ServiceStack is provide all the method which was provided by IDBConnection. Including open connection. You can manually open and close connection in ServiceStack OrmLite.

Please let me know if you needed any sample to show this. Its just a Open method of IDBConnection object that you need to call.